# OAuth & OpenID Connect - When To Use Refresh Token & Which Route To Choose

Tags: security, oauth, oauth-2.0, openid-connect

After reading about OAuth & OpenID connect, I was left with 2 questions that I couldn't find the answer to:

1. When to use the refresh token? I understand the role of refresh token but I'm not sure when it is enough to provide only access token and when need to provide both access token and refresh token? For example, if a user login to my site using his credentials (email & password). Should I only return the access token? will the answer change if I don't want the force to log out after the user closes the site? Also, if a client app has a code, should it be exchanged with access_token or both access_token and refresh token? it seems to me that the code is the replacement of the refresh token.
2. When to use /authorize route and when to use /token route? If the user login to my site with his credentials should I use the /token route or the /authorize route?

Answer (score 1):

**1)** Refresh token is used to obtain a refreshed access token. It belongs to the application which received it and must be used against the token issued authorization server. You can read more about it from [RFC6749's Refresh Token definition](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-1.5)

Access token is always issued for a typical OAuth/OpenID Connect flow. But refresh token is not issued for some instances. For example, refresh token is not issued if you use [implicit flow](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.2) (note - implicit flow is no longer recommended to use).

So in your case, if you believe there will be an access token expiration within the user's usage time, then it is better to issue a refresh token which can be used to renew the access token. Response of a refresh token request typically contain an updated refresh token (invalidating old refresh token). But this is implementation specific.

**2)** authorization endpoint is invoked through an user agent. For example this is the login dialog shown through a browser. Token endpoint is invoked through a back channel request. If you use implicit flow, you are not using token endpoint (again, this flow is no longer recommended). For authorization code flow you need to use both authorization and token ednpoints to complete the protocol.